# Searching for postcodes with different character spacing - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am in a scenario where i need to search for thousands of postcodes. On the excel spreadsheet i have been given with the postcodes they have no spacing.

e.g.

```
('PO278HI')
('PO228HI')
('PO118HI')
('PO678HI')
('PO788HI')
('PO238HI')
('PO898HI')
('PO998HI')
```

However, on the database the postcodes are saved in various formats.

e.g.

```
('PO278HI')
('PO228HI')
('PO1 18HI')
('PO678HI')
('PO788HI')
('PO23 8HI')
('PO8 98HI')
('PO99 8HI')
```

What is the easiest way i can do a search on these so that i can return the matching postcodes.

I have tried an IN statment which obviously didnt work so i tried a like statement like

```
 postcode like ('%PO278HI%')
```

which in theory works but i am dealing with so many postcodes it would take me forever to keep adding like statements.

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are additional formats caused by only spaces? Or are there different characters to be removed, etc?

Comment: Hmm.... your database data includes invalid postcodes (lines 3 and 7). The part after the space is always fixed 3 chars, format `naa`. Seems there should be some validation or cleaning of codes on the way in. The space is officially part of the postcode although it is semantically superfluous. Yes, I know I should get out more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the whitespace from the postal codes and then do the comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE REPLACE(postcode, ' ', '') = 'PO278HI';
```

Comment: You can also use `in` after the replacement.

Comment: The problem with this answer is SARGability. From experience, using `REPLACE` like that massively hinders the query; changing `WHERE postcode = 'PO278HI';` to `REPLACE(postcode, ' ', '') = 'PO278HI'` has literally caused a query i had that used to run in seconds run in 10s of minutes. For small data sets, it'll be fine, but if the OP has a lot, then the fall off could be severe.

Comment: Is there any advantage in adding a computed persisted column in which the spaces are removed? Then the work is done only once for each insert/update and the additional column is available for future querying without the overhead.

Comment: @Larnu I agree with your comment and answer +1.  I answered from a business analyst mindset where the query would be run occasionally as a one-off thing, not in production.

Comment: Yes Tim, agree there as well. If the OP is doing this as a one off, with no long term plans to do so again, then simply using `REPLACE` isn't going to be "much" of an issue; it solves the problems in the simplest method. @JohnRC yes, there certainly is, as I detail in my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The "best" way to ensure query postcodes is ensure that they have the correct formatting, or have no spaces; Simply said. I've worked with several systems, and yes, users have a tendency to not put the space, or put it in the wrong place.

Assuming we're talking about UK postcodes, the space, should, always be before the last 3 characters, so you end up with one of the following formats

```
A1 1AA
A11 1AA
AA1 1AA
AA11 1AA
A1A 1AA
```

There are a few special cases as well.

The easiest way, therefore, is to do a `REPLACE` on your column, specifically:

`REPLACE(Postcode,' ','') =...`

Then supply your postcode input without a space. The problem with this, however, is that using `REPLACE` causes the query to become non-SARGable, meaning any indexes you have can't be used.

Therefore, from experience, I've found you're better off adding a computed column to your table, preferable `PERSISTED`. You can then query against that column, and also index it (if it's `PERSISTED`).

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD Postcode_NS AS REPLACE(Postcode,' ','') PERSISTED;
```

Then, you can query against that table where a `WHERE` clause like:

```
WHERE Postcode_NS = REPLACE(@Pcode,' ','')
```

Note that the `REPLACE` around the variable won't be a problem for SARGability here.